# Storing a dispatch_source_t in an NSMutableDictionary

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdictionary, nsvalue

If I try to use a dispatch_source_t as the key in an NSMutableDictionary:

```
dispatch_source_t               source = dispatch_source_create(stuff...);
NSMutableDictionary             filesAndSources = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

filesAndSources[source] = @{stuff goes here};
```

I get the warning:

```
Sending 'dispatch_source_t' (aka 'NSObject<OS_dispatch_source> *') to parameter of incompatible type 'id<NSCopying> _Nonnull'
```

I assume it's because a dispatch_source_t doesn't use the NSCopying protocol. My solution was to stuff the dispatch_source_t into an NSValue:

```
NSValue*          val = [NSValue valueWithPointer:(__bridge const void* _Nullable)(source)];
filesAndSources[val] = @{stuff};
```

This quiets the warning, but I'm not sure if that's the right way to pass a dispatch_source_t around.

Comment: "If I try to use a dispatch_source_t as the key in an NSMutableDictionary" Can you explain why you want to do that?

Comment: So I can use the source sent to the event handler block to look up other pieces of data in the dict that go along with it. I don't have just a single local source, but many, hence the dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`NSMapTable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmaptable?language=objc) which has finer control of key and value semantics than `NS(Mutable)Dictionary`.

Pointer equality, `NSMapTableObjectPointerPersonality`, can be specified for the keys rather than requiring they conform to `NSCopying` and provide `isEqual:` and `hash` can be specified for the keys; while still using strong references to the values, `NSMapTableStrongMemory`, creating a table with:

```
[NSMapTable mapTableWithKeyOptions: NSMapTableObjectPointerPersonality
                      valueOptions:NSMapTableStrongMemory]
```

Instance methods are `objectForKey:` and `setObject:forKey:` *et al*, but you don't get the get/set indexing syntax shorthands available with `NS(Mutable)Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use dispatch source object reference as a key into a dictionary, *and you know that all of the objects used as keys exist and are valid* (this is an important requirement), then you could just use the pointer value as an integer key:

```
sources[ @( (intptr_t)source ) ] = @{stuff};
```

That's because objects don't move once created, so the integer representation of the object reference will be a constant for the lifetime of that object. Just make sure you remove the entry before destroying the object or you could end up with duplicate keys.